# Can you create an independent iOS Watch App *WITH* NFC?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nfc, watchkit

I'm trying to create an independent Watch Xcode app (AKA no connected iPhone app) with NFC capabilities. HOWEVER, every resource I find requires for there to be an iPhone app as well. No, I'm not trying to use ApplePay. This would be a unique NFC. If you also have any links to these resources, please share!

I've been digging for a direct answer for hours, so any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreNFC is not currently available on watchOS, so unfortunately no. If you look at the documentation, only iOS 11.0+ and Mac Catalyst 13.0+ are supported.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc